# Is there a way to visualize full user permission of a certain directory?

Tags: permissions, 22.04, users, visualization

Let's say that I have a directory called "test"
and user1; user2; user3; user4; user5 has full permission of "test" directory and sub-directory

Is there a way for me to visually see every user ID that has permission to this directory?

for example when you use `ls -lh` you can see the full permission related info of a certain directory and file like this right? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCwsq.png)

but what I want is to show actual users' id like below,

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root      root      4.0K Jun  3  2021 test user1 user2 user3 user4 user 5
```

It doesn't have to be exactly the same as I want, but is there a way to make ubuntu to print the user permissions of a directory as close as what I want?

Comment: How were these users given "full permission" to these directories? ACLs? Or just group membership?

Comment: Hi muru, I think I was asking a stupid question, I searched a bit more after watching your comment and there is no way to set multiple user access permission via chmod

Comment: I have to use ACL as you said, Is there any good step by step tutorial that I can look into that you know?

Thank you for your previous answer